# Alternative to /proc/bus/usb/devices

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

/proc/bus/usb/devices should not be used anymore (and can't be mounted anymore on Ubuntu 11.04)

But what is an alternative to it, for use in a terminal?

I could easily grep that output to look for a certain device, but I'm lost in all the /sys/ entries...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely clear on what information you are looking to extract from that file, but almost certainly the output of the `lsusb` command will be able to help you.

Answer (score 8):

lsusb either just lists the devices, or very verbose and dumps a lot of information, but is missing which driver owns each, what interface and alternative configuration is currently selected and in use.

v3.5-rc1 removed `CONFIG_USB_DEVICEFS` and in effect `/proc/bus/usb/devices`, but fortunately it is available in `/sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices` at least 2.6.39 kernel has it.

Comment: The pointer to `/sys/kernel/debug/usb` is helpful: `/proc/bus/usb` may be gone, but [current documentation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/usb/acm.txt) still points to it.