# What is the difference between /dev/usb, /proc/bus/usb and /sys/bus/usb?

Tags: linux, usb

In terms of content, what is the difference between these 4 folders?

- `/dev/usb`
- `/proc/bus/usb`
- `/sys/bus/usb`
- `/sys/class/usb_device`

I found many symlinks between those folders, many redundant information. More generically what is the idea/purpose in the first place of each of these folders?

Answer (score 6):

Take from the wikipedia:

**/dev**
Essential devices, e.g., /dev/null.

[**/proc**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//proc)
Virtual filesystem documenting kernel and process status as text files, e.g., uptime, network. In Linux, corresponds to a procfs mount.

[**/sys**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs)
Modern Linux distributions include a /sys directory as a virtual filesystem (sysfs, comparable to /proc, which is a procfs), which stores and allows modification of the devices connected to the system, whereas many traditional UNIX and Unix-like operating systems use /sys as a symbolic link to the kernel source tree

Comment: Thanks but my question is specific to usb and usb only.

Answer (score 2):

as also mentioned [https://su/q/alternative-to-proc-bus-usb-devices](https://superuser.com/questions/327383/alternative-to-proc-bus-usb-devices), /proc/bus/usb/devices is deprecated. see [Kconfig documentation](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/USB_DEVICEFS.html).